# How to get only matched substring start , end indexes from string object

Tags: java, regex

I want to use wild card functionality,

if pattern is * test*  and string is  **abctestbcd**  I have to get **start index=3**, **endIndex=6**

Comment: This is a simple API call, are you sure you need help for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
String searchString = "test";
String s = "abctestbcd";

int startIndex = s.indexOf("test");
int endIndex = startIndex+searchString.length()-1;
System.out.println(startIndex);
System.out.println(endIndex);
```

If it is possible to hat multiple matches use it in a loop:

```
String searchString = "test";
String s = "abctestbcdtest";

int startIndex = -1;
do {
    startIndex = s.indexOf("test", startIndex+1);
    int endIndex = startIndex+searchString.length()-1;
    if (startIndex != -1){
        System.out.println(startIndex);
        System.out.println(endIndex);
    }
} while(startIndex != -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pattern` can help you.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
// Check all occurrences
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end());
    System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Combination of [subString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) and [indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) functions.